# Realm - Pesquisar conteúdo com acentuação

Tags: android, acentuação, realmdb

Pelo que li, o Realm ainda não da suporte para termos com acentuação. Queria saber se existe então alguma forma de consultar os dados do Realm ignorando a acentuação. Por exemplo, pesquiso por "veterinario" (sem acento) e o realm me retorne o "veterinário" (com acento) que esta salvo na base de dados.

Sei que posso pegar toda a lista e jogar em um ArrayList, e com ela fazer um algoritmo para ignorar os acentos. Porém, a base de dados é grande e o tempo de resposta tem que ser instantâneo deixando esta prática inviável.

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu utilizo um função minha que remove os acentos de uma string. Talvez se você aplicar esta função no termo pesquisado, e depois jogar este termo para o realm resolva a situação:

```
public static String removerAcentos(String valor) {
        if(valor == null)
            return "";

        String comAcentos = "ÄÅÁÂÀÃäáâàãÉÊËÈéêëèÍÎÏÌíîïìÖÓÔÒÕöóôòõÜÚÛüúûùÇçºª°´`Çô";
        String semAcentos = "AAAAAAaaaaaEEEEeeeeIIIIiiiiOOOOOoooooUUUuuuuCc     Co";
        for (int i = 0; i < comAcentos.length(); i++)
        {
            valor = valor.replace(comAcentos.charAt(i), semAcentos.charAt(i));
        }
        return valor;
    }
```